# Elegantly handling different classes with same properties in 3rd party library

Tags: c#

My c# app uses a third party library which has multiple classes that don't share an interface or base class, yet have multiple properties in common (the properties may or may not have the same name, but they essentially store the same information). Just to give a trivial example:

```
class A
{
   int Prop1;
   string Prop2;
}

class B
{
   int Prop1;
   string Prop2b;
}
```

Note how Prop1 has the same name for both classes, but Prop2 and Prop2b have different names (though they are semantically the same).

In one instance, the classes are actually structs.

This results in a lot of duplicate code on my side to do the same thing to each class (just another trivial example: appending Prop1 to Prop2 or Prop2b). What is an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: You could probably try with `dynamic`, but your question is not clear enough to say more.

Comment: Are they partial classes?

Comment: @Marcin: interesting idea, but would not quite work since the property names are sometime slightly different (Prop2 vs Prop2b).

Comment: @Shoe: no, they are not partial classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write adapters that do derive from the interface, for example

3rd party classes

```
class Car
{
   int CarId;
   string CarName;
}

class Motorcycle
{
   int MotoId;
   string MotoName;
}
```

Your interface

```
public interface IVehicle
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
}
```

And your classes

```
class MyCar : IVehicle
{
   private Car _car;
   public MyCar (Car car){ _car = car }
   int Id; // returns _car.CarId
   string Name; // returns _car.CarName
}

class MyMotorcycle : IVehicle
{
   private Motorcycle _moto;
   public MyCar (Motorcycle moto){ _moto = moto; }
   int Id; // returns _moto.MotoId
   string Name; // returns _moto.MotoName
}
```

Now you can use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interface and then create an adapter for each type to adapt it to that interface. If there's enough classes to warrant the extra complexity, you could use Castle.DynamicProxy to create the implementations on the fly.